# App crashing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider after using proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, dexprotector

My app has facebook login and facebook share. I had configured my manifest file as specified in facebook android SDK documentation.

App is working properly in release and debug modes.

After I create release APK with 'minifyEnabled true' , app is crashing at startup with the following log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pocketium.trollmonkey-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4619)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pocketium.trollmonkey-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5072)
... 11 more
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I tried disabling shrinking and optimization and added keep option to keep facebook classes, but app still crashes. I am new to android. Searched a lot in google, but could not find a solution.

**UPDATE Dec 1 , 2015**

I tried creating release APK with proguard enabled in linux. There is no issue when I create apk on my linux machine. But the apks that I create in my windows machine as well as mac crashes at start up. I did not change any code while taking build in linux environment.

PS: I tried Dex protector and obfuscated release apk that I created with proguard disabled. APK created by dexprotector is working properly.

Comment: Post the proguard config file

Comment: proguard-rules.pro currently  contains only  -ignorewarnings .

Comment: this is by gradle file https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3ueqhd5u0tdpzb/gradle.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

For me updating gradle plugin to `1.5.0` and rebuilding fixed the issue:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        ...
    }
}
```

My facebook-sdk version is `4.8.1`

Gradle version is `2.7`. Can be found in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add gradle plugin dependency in the build.gradle in the root of your project (and use 1.5 like Nikita says) instead of in the build.gradle in the android-client folder. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing `proguard-android-optimize.txt` to `proguard-android.txt` does work.

Try:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.set("dexprotector.configFile", "${projectDir}/dexprotector.xml")
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why, but once upon a time the dexprotector support told me to change it because there's a known bug using r8 and proguard optimization files, so I tried and it worked. No more details about that, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep        class com.facebook.** { *; }
```

include line above in your proguard config.

tldr;

if you are only going to include "-ignorewarnings" as the only , config directive to proguard, then dont use it.

If you want learn proguard/android then google some of the sample config files and google some on the usage of how to preserve both interface defs and public classes from library projects in android/proguard.

Comment: Tried the above config. But still crashing.